# Proof by induction: $2^n > n$

Tags: induction

Base is $2^1 > 1$.

Now we assume $2^n > n$ and try to obtain $2^{n+1} > (n+1)$.

If I can use $2^n > 1$, I could just add that to $2^n > n$ and get $2^{n+1} > (n+1)$ but I don't know how to obtain the form $2^n > 1$ in order to use it. Is there a different approach to proving this instead of directly trying to deduce to a specific form $2^{n+1} > (n+1)$?

Comment: **Hint:** Multiply the induction hypothesis by $2$.

Comment: @Git Don't we then have to prove that $2n > n+1$?

Comment: Yes, but $2n=n+n$ and since $n\ge 1$, it follows.

Comment: You could obtain the form $2^n > 1$ by e.g. observing that it is equal to $2\cdot 2^{n-1}$, and the product of two natural numbers one of which is greater than $1$, is greater than $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n = 1$, then $2^n = 2^1 = 2$, and 
$n = 1$, so the inequality holds true for $n = 1$.

For the induction hypothesis, we assume $2^k > k$ for some $k > 1$.
However, 
$$2^{k + 1} = (2^k)(2^1) 
= (2^k)(2) $$
The induction hypothesis gives 
$$2^{k + 1} = (2^k)(2^1) 
= (2^k)(2)> k(2) 
= 2k 
= k + k $$
Since $k \geq 1 $, 
$$2^{k + 1}> k + 1 $$
Q.E.D.